# Expression expected after raising event

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If RaiseEvent Button1.Click = True Then
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim Fnum As Integer = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Snum As Integer = TextBox2.Text
        result = Fnum + Snum
        Label1.Text = result
```

hello, im having trouble with this code. Im trying to get it to say when the buttons pressed, it activates this other button's method. Im getting an error at the `RaiseEvent` part. It puts a squiggly line on the R and says "expression expected. Sorry im kinda new to VB and need a bit of help with it. Thanks

Comment: RaiseEvent is not the correct statement to be using here.  It does not produce a value and therefore can not be compared.  [VB RaiseEvent statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed.aspx)

Comment: It's not clear what you thing that code should do.

Comment: There are *many* calculator samples online. Use The Google young Skywalker.

Answer (score 0):

`RaiseEvent` is used for raising events, not to find out whether an event has been raised or not.

Based on your comments in other post, you may want to maintain a flag to track when your operator buttons were clicked.

Something like this,

```
Dim OperatorClicked As Boolean

Private Sub OperatorButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
    OperatorClicked = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If OperatorClicked Then
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim Fnum As Integer = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Snum As Integer = TextBox2.Text
        result = Fnum + Snum '-- you need to modify this too to specify correct operator
        Label1.Text = result
    End If
    OperatorClicked = False
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Instead of keeping a boolean flag to track whether operator was clicked or not, we use a string to track which operator was clicked. Here I assume that the button Text has +, -, /, * respectively. (However the ideal way would be to use the `Tag` property. This will help you keep the display text disassociated from code.)

```
Dim OperatorClicked As String

Private Sub OperatorButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click
    OperatorClicked = CType(sender, Button).Text.Trim
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    If OperatorClicked <> "" Then
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim Fnum As Integer = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Snum As Integer = TextBox2.Text
        Select Case OperatorClicked
        Case "+"
            result = Fnum + Snum 
        Case "-"
            result = Fnum - Snum 

        '-- similarly other cases

        End Select

        Label1.Text = result
    End If
    OperatorClicked = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much you have really helped out but im still really new and need help with one more thing. How would i modify it to the correct operator? I dont know how i would use an if statement here, like 'if buttonx was clicked, do this' so could you please help? much apreciated

Comment: I updated my post above to show one way how this can be done.

Comment: 'If OperatorClicked <> "" Then'  for that line do i have to specify what button has been clicked? By the way yes i am using * / + - but putting them in the cases didnt do anything becuase it didnt refer to the button. Thank you so much you are so close to helping me finish my first calculator.

Comment: What I posted should have worked. Probably your button text is not exactly + - / * etc. Maybe you have spaces in your Button Text. I updated the code above and added `.Trim` ; that should fix it.